# Object.keys Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data as follows,

```
var data={'08/06/2020': Array(1), '08/07/2020': Array(1), '08/08/2020': Array(1), '08/09/2020': Array(1), '08/10/2020': Array(1), …}
```

Trying to loop through the object keys, but getting an undefined error,

```
data.keys(function(v,i){ 
   // some code
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried `Object.keys` instead of `keys`?

Comment: It's because [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is a method that only exists in the [`Object` built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and delete the `,...` at the end of your object.

```js
var data={'08/06/2020': Array(1), '08/07/2020': Array(1), '08/08/2020': Array(1), '08/09/2020': Array(1), '08/10/2020': Array(1)}

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```